# Обработка событий на select

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

*Всем доброе время суток)*

Взял пример с [сайта](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/29/simple-effects-for-drop-down-lists/),  **Demo 6**

Все нормально работает, правда не могу понять как на `<select>` поставить обработчик, который бы брал от туда *value*.
То есть, чтоб при изменении селектора, менялся "контент".

---

Вот код самого селектора:

```
    <select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
    <option value="-1" selected>Choose an animal</option>
    <option value="1" class="icon-monkey">Monkey</option>
    <option value="2" class="icon-bear">Bear</option>
    <option value="3" class="icon-squirrel">Squirrel</option>
    <option value="4" class="icon-elephant">Elephant</option>
</select>
```

, но на самой странице уже отображается

```
    <div class="cd-dropdown">
    <span>Choose an animal</span>
    <input type="hidden" name="cd-dropdown">
    <ul>
        <li data-value="1"><span class="icon-monkey">Monkey</span></li>
        <li data-value="2"><span class="icon-bear">Bear</span></li>
        <li data-value="3"><span class="icon-squirrel">Squirrel</span></li>
        <li data-value="4"><span class="icon-elephant">Elephant</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

, я так понял , что эта "трансформация" происходит в

> jquery.dropdown.js

---

создал 2 формы , forma1 с id="f1", и аналогично form2 c id="f2" , одну форму сделал hide
поставил на селект

> onChange="func(this.value)"
> а вот сама функция

```
    function func(par){ 
if(par==1){ 
document.getElementById('f'+par).style.display=''; 
document.getElementById('f'+2).style.display='none'; 
}else{

document.getElementById('f'+par).style.display=''; 
document.getElementById('f'+1).style.display='none'; 
} 
}
```

если это обычный селектор, то функция работает.

---

при выборе разных селектов, меняется значение *value*

```
<input type="hidden" name="cd-dropdown">
```

Подскажите как , обратиться к этому инпуту, и при изменении значения чтоб оно запускало func().
Заранее, огромное спасибо))

Answer (score 1):

Похоже что вам и надо значит следить только за скрытым инпутом

```
$('body').on('change', 'input[name=cd-dropdown]', function(){
    // ваша функция тут
})
```

Comment: аа..да) тупонул)) подключил, уже есть, но при выборе другого пункта в селекторе, в скрытом инпуте _value_ меняется, а вот формы не меняются.
Возможно надо обращаться  не _this.value_  , а как то по другому?

Comment: Прошу прощения, что морочу голову)
1) http://jsfiddle.net/S1ash/m3R9A/10/ если выбираю первый раз, то нормально, а во второй уже выводиться вторая форма, и они обе уже не исчезают))
2) На селекторе оно работает, а вот на инпуте - нет. Опять проблема с тем, как взять value у инпута.

P.S. Вот [страничка][1] 

[1]: http://depositfiles.com/files/kpjedaikr

Comment: пффф... теперь мне нужна помощь гуру в понимании почему предыдущий вариант не работал, а вот так работает http://jsfiddle.net/m3R9A/11/

Comment: Все равно из _inputa_ оно не берет значение =(
Если в консоле прописать 

     a(2) 
то оно нормально все выводить в браузере.